# Bash script conditional do while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm struggling with syntax of do while loop with 2 conditions inside the while statement:

```
while [[ supervisorctl status | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}' != 'RUNNING' ]] && [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; do
       supervisorctl start $1
       sleep 3
       $count=$count -1
done
```

when i run bash -n on my script to check for syntax error i get the following output:

```
line 31: conditional binary operator expected
line 31: syntax error near `status'
line 31: `        while [[ supervisorctl status | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}' != 'RUNNING' ]] && [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; do'
```

can someone please help me figure the correct syntax?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is a good place to start. Short answer: You shouldn't use `[[ ]]` here at all.

Comment: Well, not unless your goal is to test for output from the pipeline, in which case it should be `[[ $(...pipeline...) ]]`. But it's better practice to design your pipeline so the last component of it has a true or false exit status so you don't need to inspect output at all.

Comment: Consider `supervisorctl status | awk -v service="$1" 'BEGIN { retval=0 }; $1 == service && $2 == "RUNNING" { retval=1 } END { exit retval }'` as such a condition you could use, to not even need `grep` either.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
i didn't really got you...
However, if for example i just want to check this statement inside the while:
`supervisorctl status | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}' != 'RUNNING' `?
even this returns an error:
        `while [[ supervisorctl status | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}' != 'RUNNING' ]]; do
                supervisorctl start $1
                sleep 3
                $count=$count -1
        done`

Comment: Once again, **do not use `[[`** here.

Comment: `while (( count )) && supervisorctl status | awk -v service="$1" 'BEGIN { retval=0 }; $1 == service && $2 == "RUNNING" { retval=1 } END { exit retval }'; do supervisorctl start "$1"; sleep 3; count=$(( count - 1 )); done`

Comment: Or, if you really insist on sticking with your old pipeline: `while [[ $(supervisorctl status | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}' != 'RUNNING') ]] && (( count )); do ...`

Comment: Thanks again, it works.
can you please explain a bit what you did here? 
`BEGIN { retval=0 }; $1 == service && $2 == "RUNNING" { retval=1 } END { exit retval }`
I'm still a beginner in bash and want to understand